# PCF autoscaler is duplicating data in each instance

Tags: database, pipeline, cloud-foundry, autoscaling

I have a Java Rest API with Azure Database. I need to use the autoscaler to keep it performing well.

Here is the way I create the Autoscaler service (using pipeline and VMWare Apps Manager):

***autoscaler:

nb-instances-min: 3

nb-instances-max: 6

threshold-min: 750

threshold-max: 1500

rule-type: http_latency

rule-sub-type: avg_95th***

The instances are created as expected, but all data, in the database, are loaded (duplicated) in each instance.

Questions:
How to solve this problem? Is it possible to force the BD service to stay in a specific instance? (example: instance 0 only)?

What rule type could we use to solve? Custom? or other in the list below (all types possible)?
***CPU Utilization

HTTP Throughput

Container Memory

RabbitMQ

Custom

Compare***

Thanks in advance,

I read the documentation, but I didn't find, on that, a solution to this problem:
https://docs.pivotal.io/application-service/2-8/appsman-services/autoscaler/about-app-autoscaler.html